# Как сделать кланы в базе данных?

Tags: база-данных, разработка-игр

Я пишу телеграм бота на python. Игра, в которой можно развиваться, бизнесу, работы, кланы и др.

А вот что на счёт кланов, как их реализовать в бд. У меня есть общая таблица, айди, уровень, деньги и др.

Так понимаю для клана нужно создавать новую таблицу, в которой будет хранится название, описание, прокачки и др. Но как в бд реализовать список участников, кто то будет лидером, новичком и т.п., может можно как-то вкладывать таблицы друг в друга.

Comment: Третья таблица с тремя столбцами — id участника, id клана, роль. Классическая связь многие-ко-многим.

Comment: Благодарю, могли бы вы написать в ответ? Поставлю галочку)